# Cycling Jerseys

Tags: clothes

I have several cycling jerseys that have writing on the collars. Each one has the writing on the inside of the collar. Where nobody will ever see it except when it isn't being worn. Why?

Comment: Could it be the signature/autograph of another rider, perhaps one who wore the jersey? A photo might help.

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se]! More info might help. What does the writing say?

Comment: I have a Trek Factory jersey that says, "go and take it" and a USMC jersey that say's "Marines" on the inside and others. The very first time I saw it I thought it was just a mistake at the factory.

Comment: Advertising and packaging - you the prospective purchaser can see it when you're browsing in the shop or online or in a catalogue.

Comment: Could be a now more experienced sponsor who did not put "On the outside" in the contract fine print.

Comment: @mattnz securing sponsors is a non-trivial exercise, this would be a bad strategy for maintaining or procuring new sponsors.

Answer (score 4):

This is a message personally to the wearer of the jersey, for inspiration or so other sort.  Its like having a tattoo that isn't visible to the world.  Its enjoyment for oneself.

Comment: This is done on the inside of suit jackets and sport coats all the time; it's intended for the wearer of the garment to notice.